# Calling Destructor within Object Method in PHP

Tags: php, oop, destructor

I have an object that can be used, or eaten, or whatnot in PHP. In any case, it ends up gone. I have an abstract protected method called `activate()`, which is called by a public method `useItem()`.

Is it possible for `useItem()` to destroy itself after calling `activate()`? If not, what is the best way of making sure the item is permanently gone?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you have something like:

```
class AbstractMyClass {
    abstract protected function activate();
    public function useItem() {
        //...
        $this->activate();
        //...
    }
}

class MyClass extends AbstractMyClass { /* ... */ }
```

In this case, no, there's no way to make the object being destructed after calling `useItem` short of:

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->useItem();
unset($obj);
//if there are cyclic references, the object won't be destroyed except
//in PHP 5.3 if the garbage collector is called
```

Of course, you could encapsulate the destroyable object in another one:

```
class MyClass extends AbstractMyClass { /* ... */ }
class MyWrapper {
    private $inner;
    public function __construct($object) {
        $this->inner = $object;
    }
    public function useItem() {
        if ($this->inner === null)
            throw new InvalidStateException();
        $this->inner->useItem();
        $this->inner = null;
    }
}

$obj = new MyWrapper(new MyClass());
$obj->useItem();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply unset() it if you wish.

Realistically, the [garbage collector or GC](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) in PHP will do all the work you need once the variable goes out of scope or there are zero references to it. To be clear, the GC got a major rework in PHP 5.3, so if you're using 5.2.x, you may still have some performance issues.